# Want to use the feature of Address card view of Microsoft Outlook in Java

Tags: java, swing, outlook, jtable

There is Address Cards view when we click on Contacts in Microsoft Outlook. I want to use this same feature in my application. I am using swing. But didnt get whether the view is a bunch of JTables created at run time or some cells of JTable are highlighted that way? Need your suggestions to create view like this.

I have attached an example image available on the net.

[image: There is no contacts saved in my Outlook so copied from internet]

Comment: A screenshot would be nice as I(and possibly others) don't have outlook.

Comment: thanks, I think Puce's answer is the direction you should start in.

Comment: @jzd,yes I am just going through that link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core Swing component that comes closest is [`JList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), I think, with [`setLayoutOrientation(JList.VERTICAL_WRAP)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setLayoutOrientation%28int%29) and a custom renderer.

Answer (score 0):

look at the components in l2fProd ... a wonderful library
http://l2fprod.com/common/